# C# Combine many IList<char> to make a new List

Tags: c#, combinations, permutation, ilist

I have some permutations of type  IList each one having 6
elements e.g. 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2

So in my permutations collection I may have 2 lists looking like 1, 1,
3, 2, 2, 2 & the other as 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2

I need to combine them to get the resulting combination being 1, 1 , 2/3, 2/3, 2, 2.

But the combining needs to be applied to all permutations in the list. The bellow code suggested works, however the combining should be reducing the items in the collection, but after combining them Im left with the same amount of permutations combined?

```
foreach (IList<char> p in permutationCollection)
    {
        var result = p.Zip(permutationCollection.ElementAt(x + 1), (first, second) => { if (first != second) { return first + " / " + second; } else return second.ToString(); });
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to show what you've tried before trying to get people to help otherwise it can be perceived that you're simply coming here to get people to write some code for you.

Comment: Do you just have 2 lists or multiple?

Comment: I'm not clear on your example result.  Can you explain exactly how you are combining the values {1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2} with {1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2} to get {1, 1, 2/3, 2/3, 2, 2}.  And does 2/3 mean two thirds (0.66) or 2 and 3?  If the latter how is that represented in your set?

Comment: @juharr It means *2 or/and 3*, i.e. he/she is collapsing the notation {1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2} and {1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2} into one {1, 1, 2/3, 2/3, 2, 2}.

Comment: @haxsta Only for two elements in or for any combination of elements? That question counts both for the number of lList items as for 'how many of the 6'?  And if for any combination, what has precedence - the maximum number of lList items you can combine into one, or something else? Not only is your code missing, but your problem statement is very ambiguous. **You need to add many more actual examples**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq Zip will do the trick http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx

i.e.

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2 };
int[] words = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2 };

var result = numbers.Zip(words, (first, second) => {if(first != second) {return first + " / " + second;} else return second.ToString(); });
```

Comment: This looks to be working, thanks @marcinn. Now my collection obviously has many items (Sometimes hundreds) how do I combine them all. i have tried in a loop taking the next item but that wont combine them all. foreach (IList<char> p in permutationCollection)
            {
                var result = p.Zip(permutationCollection.ElementAt(x + 1), (first, second) => { if (first != second) { return first + " / " + second; } else return second.ToString(); });
            }